# Finding out how many customers log into Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to determine how many returning customers `login` into their account whether it be at the checkout stage or simply via "`My Account`".

I have looked for something related to this in the backend but can't find anything.

It is looking likely that I will have to create an observer for the 'customer_customer_authenticated' event and create my own `logs` unless anyone else knows of another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a `customer_login` event you can watch/observe.

From [Session.php](http://freegento.com/doc/d4/d74/class_mage___customer___model___session.html#d870c94a5775868891f6c50b9818d627), `login($username, $password)`

```
00161     {
00162         $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
00163             ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
00164 
00165         if ($customer->authenticate($username, $password)) {
00166             $this->setCustomer($customer);
00167             Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
00168             return true;
00169         }
00170         return false;
00171     }
```

Just log `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getReferer();` and/or `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();` on your observer.